# 1 or zero instances within regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex expression (below) but how do I restrict this to one 1 instance or no instances of `[. -:]`.

```
if re.match("[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([. -:]?[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){%d}$" % x, self.input_value):
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does it not already? You already have `[. -:]?`, which does exactly what you want. What does it not match that it should?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to allow for `x` repetitions of the overall pattern, but only one of the repetitions can have the punctuation subpattern? What I would suggest is to look for matches with or without the punctuation pattern, then discard any match which contains two or more instances of the punctuation pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?` on a group makes it optional, which would be 1 or 0.

Edited to remove the explicit version

Comment: I don't know that `{0,1}` has the same semantics for greediness as `?` (i.e. I don't think `/ab*{0,1}b/` is the same as `/ab*?b/`. However, in many cases, they should be the same

Comment: That's not relevant. `*?` is not the same token as `?`. `/ab*{0,1}b/ is the same as /(?:ab*)?b/` (ignoring the subpattern).

Comment: Downvote removed - I though you were suggesting `{1,0}` over `?` was the fix. My mistake. Both are equally valid here.

Comment: Fair enough. I second you comment to OP now as well... but i guess ill leave the answer for now